# CMake Error : No externals download dir set

Tags: cmake

When I run this command :

```
cmake ../CCCP/3rdparty             -DINSTALL_ROOT=$BUILDROOT/i             -DEXTERNALS_DOWNLOAD_DIR=$BUILDROOT/d             -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=BUILDROOT/i
```

I get this error :

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:28 (message):
>     No externals download dir set.  Use -DEXTERNALS_DOWNLOAD_DIR
>   -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
>   See also "/Users/Apple/BUILDROOT/b/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".

can anyone help me please ?

Comment: Perhaps you want to share you CMake log?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more context about this problem? What are you trying to build?